# Mit-scheme, recursion error with built-in filter function

Tags: filter, scheme

```
(filter even? (numb-2tx 100000))

;Aborting!: maximum recursion depth exceeded
;;numb-2tx generates a list from 2 to x, even for very large values of x (tested with 2000000)
```

When I try to apply the filter function to very long lists (>40,000 or so) I run into the maximum recursion depth error.

Is there a similar built-in that doesn't run into this problem, or will I have to come up with a tail-recursive equivalent on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start MIT Scheme with the `--stack` option.  Like this:

```
$ mit-scheme --stack 10000
```

Here was my result with the out-of-the-box stack and also with a stack of 1000:

```
> (length (filter even? (iota 1000000)))

;Aborting!: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Then, after using `--stack 10000`:

```
> (length (filter even? (iota 1000000)))

;Value: 500000
```

It is somewhat disturbing to know that `filter` has this apparently non-tail-recursive behavior.